# Is this considered to be the correct way of SRP? [C#]

Tags: c#, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I'm creating a game for a school project and one of the requirements that I need to meet is using SOLID principles in my C# code.

I'ts pretty hard to understand the concepts of SOLID principles that's why I'm asking here to confirm that my implementation of SRP is correct.

*This is my SRP class that just plays a soundeffect, the sound comes from a list inside the **SoundEffects** class.*

```cs
public class PlaySoundEffect 
{
    public static void PlayEffect(string soundeffect, float volume, float pitch, float pan)
    {
        SoundEffects.Effects[soundeffect].Play(volume, pitch, pan);
    }
}
```

*And this is how it gets called in one of my level classes whenever the user collides with an enemy.*

```cs
PlaySoundEffect.PlayEffect(SoundEffects.DEATH, 1f, 0.75f, 0);
```

Is this considered to be SRP?

If not how can I achieve it?

Comment: It's a shame they teach you a concept without any method to check if you achieved something in your practice. I had to clarify your post and found this: https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/single-responsibility-principle/ What do you think?

Comment: It was very strange, I am currently in the second year of my college education. We received 2 months of theory lessons and then we were left to our own to put together a project. I assume my piece of code is SRP because that's how I understood how it should work. Waiting to see what my review will be, after the project deadline.

Comment: Calling something an "SRP class" doesn't make any sense. You might has well have called it "'flibbitygoop". SRP is not the class's purpose, it's a guiding principle used when writing code. On the whole, SOLID can't be applied to static classes because static classes can't participate in inheritance. SRP can be, to some extent, but the rest can't. Whether you've applied SRP correctly in `PlaySoundEffect` depends on whether your consider 1) looking up the sound effect (`SoundEffects.Effects[soundeffect]`), and 2) playing the sound effect (`Play(volume, pitch, pan)`) to be "singular" in purpose.

Comment: It's still very confusing to me but I guess that makes sense. Looking up the sound and playing the sound effect is the only thing it's does and it's only purpose is to just play it, so I guess it's singular? Which makes it SRP, right?

Comment: Part of why you're confused is that you're using the term wrong. "SRP" is not a state of being. I'm going to stop using "SRP" because you need to see how the term fits grammatically. The Single Responsibility Principle is about what you do and how you do it, not what something "is". Your class's (or method's) responsibility may be singular, but that doesn't "make it the Single Responsibility Principle". Rather it means that "you've applied the Single Responsibility Principle".

Comment: When you use the term "SRP", expand it to "the Single Responsibility Principle" and then ask yourself if you've used those words meaningfully. That will help you start understanding what the Single Responsibility Principle is and whether you're applying it in your code. There's more to it, but this is one tool you can use to improve your understanding. The same can be said of just about any other acronym you encounter.